# Emptying and adding new items in the list in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've an jquery mobile list with some list items. I simply want to remove old items and add new items in it dynamically. I have tried the following code but it doesn't remove the previous list items and adds new items below them.

```
  <div data-role="page" id="main">
  <div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview" id="listing">
  </ul>
   <button onclick="loadList()">Click</button>
   </div>
    </div>

   var  c1 = 0;
   var c2 = 10;
   function loadList() {
    $('#listing').empty();
    location.reload();
   for(var i = c1; i<c2; i++) {
    $('#listing').append('<li>'+i+'</li>');
     }
    c1+=1;
    c2+=1;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first you must write your JavaScript code into the `<script>` tag.(If your write inside of script tag edit your question and add script tag).Your code works correct.But there is one issue.When your are calling `location.reload()` it refreshes your page,so it adds items into your `ul` but then after reloading it removes them again.So you don't see any changes.If you want it to work,remove `location.reload()`

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
  <div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview" id="listing">
  </ul>
   <button onclick="loadList()">Click</button>
   </div>
    </div>

<script>
   var  c1 = 0;
   var c2 = 10;
   function loadList() {
    $('#listing').empty();
    location.reload(); // <- comment this or remove
   for(var i = c1; i<c2; i++) {
    $('#listing').append('<li>'+i+'</li>');
     }
    c1+=1;
    c2+=1;
   };
</script>
```

Comment: I know they must be in <script></script>. $('#listing li').remove() isn't showing any content of the list. Not even the previous one.

Comment: see my edited answer.The problem is in location.reload()